# Windows Server App fabric cache vs. Enterprise Library Cache

Tags: caching, distributed-caching

Could someone please help me to understand/decide which of the caching library between appfabric cache and ent. library caching block is good?

Below is my requirement:
1. Support web server farm.
2. able to store upto 500k .Net object lists

THank you

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise Caching block is a local or 1st level caching solution while AppFabric is a distributed or 2nd level caching solution.You can not compare both.

But considering your requirements, I would recommend you to go with a 2nd level caching solution since it for a server farm, a distributed environment i presume.

The number of .NET objects that can cache depend on the size per object and the total cache size.There is no limitation on the number of objects that can be stored in 2nd level cache.

Comment: Read this.It shows the drawbacks of Enterprise Library cache as 1st level cache and explains the benefits of a 2nd level cache. http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/caching-application-block-index.html